# Expand the topic request interface

Tags: feature-request, documentation-topics, documentation-proposals

**Topic requests need more information**

Browsing through the topic requests doesn't give much guidance towards what people actually wanted a topic for.

I was looking in C# out of curiosity to see if there were any topic requests. There was only one, which was fine, but it was terribly lacking in content to create an entire topic on; and it wasn't the OP's fault.

[image]

This topic is probably far too broad. There should perhaps be a more granular set of topics each with their own related examples that this is broken out into. However, that is not easy to relate because the topic request is literally just a title and a comment.

For instance, in order for Area 51 to consider a topic "defined" it requires 40 questions each with 10 upvotes. I know that is apples and oranges in some ways, but the mindset of having at least some expanded definition is beneficial in my opinion.

There needs to be more space available to flesh out what a topic may look like and maybe even some possible example names -- or at least just *one* possible example name.

However, at present all that is actually required is one sentence. Even the descriptive comment is noted as (optional).

[image]

This interface and process needs to be expanded in order to create higher quality content. Without a driving force for desired topics, it leaves many users guessing at what the community wants when there is a perfectly good tool available for determining the actual need.

Comment: Maybe ask them to write the questions they think the topic should be able to answer.  I know people aren't really that great at writing questions, but at least they've had some practice.